# Difference Between Querying Table Directly and Querying Function that Returns that Same Table

Tags: postgresql, set-returning-functions

I would like to have a function that returns a TABLE.  I know the user can use the function call in selects and joins just like a table.  However, will the select/join be able to use the indexes of the source table that the function TABLE returned?

For example:
Will `"select id from permitted_resources() where id = 1"` be the same as `"select id from resources where id = 5"`?  (Assuming that there is an index on resources table id column.)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION permitted_resources()
  RETURNS TABLE (id   int, name varchar(10)) AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY
   SELECT r.id, r.name from resources r; 
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Will "select id from permitted_resources() where id = 1" be the same as "select id from resources where id = 5"*?

No it will not. A PL/pgSQL function is a black box for the optimizer.

If you want to achieve something like that, use a `language sql` function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION permitted_resources()
  RETURNS TABLE (id   int, name varchar(10)) AS
$func$
   SELECT r.id, r.name from resources r; 
$func$  
LANGUAGE sql
stable;
```

---

We can test this with the following setup:

```
create table test 
(
  id integer primary key, 
  some_nr integer default random() * 1000 + 1,
  some_date date default current_date,
  some_text text default md5(random()::text)
);

insert into test (id) 
select *
from generate_series(1,1e6);
```

Now create one PL/pgSQL function:

```
create function get_data1()
returns setof test
as
$$
begin
 return query
   select *
   from test;
end;   
$$
language plpgsql
stable;
```

And a SQL function:

```
create function get_data2()
returns setof test
as
$$
 select *
 from test;
$$
language sql
stable;
```

Let's see how the execution plans look:

```
explain (analyze)
select *
from get_data1() -- this is the PL/pgSQL function
where id = 1234;
```

Yields the following execution plan:

```
Function Scan on get_data1  (cost=0.25..4.75 rows=5 width=44) (actual time=261.033..361.218 rows=1 loops=1)
  Filter: (id = 1234)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 999999
Planning Time: 0.033 ms
Execution Time: 371.302 ms
```

Apparently it first retrieves all rows, then discards them again

However,

```
explain (analyze)
select *
from get_data2() -- the "SQL" function
where id = 1234;
```

Yields the following execution plan:

```
Index Scan using test_pkey on test  (cost=0.42..2.43 rows=1 width=45) (actual time=0.015..0.017 rows=1 loops=1)
  Index Cond: (id = 1234)
Planning Time: 0.119 ms
Execution Time: 0.031 ms
```

The function isn't even mentioned anymore in the plan. Not surprisingly, a plain select yields the same plan:

```
explain (analyze)
select *
from test
where id = 1234;
```

```
Index Scan using test_pkey on test  (cost=0.42..2.43 rows=1 width=45) (actual time=0.014..0.014 rows=1 loops=1)
  Index Cond: (id = 1234)
Planning Time: 0.058 ms
Execution Time: 0.026 ms
```

---

I don't know if this holds true for more complex queries, but a simple join between such a function and another table shows the same behaviour.